# Making an Oracle Apex report table element read-only

Tags: oracle-apex

Greetings:

Is there anyway to make an apex report table cell (or even the entire report itself) conditionally read-only in Apex 3.2? I don't see the "read-only" box anywhere in the options; tried searching everywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a simple answer.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do - e.g. what condition would make the cell read-only, does it vary from row to row, etc.?

Comment: Sure. Based on the authorization level of the user, I want to make the entire table read only (For example the user has read-only permissions). It does not vary from row to row. Thanks for the response Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole tabform is to be made read-only for particular users, you can do this at rendering time rather than using Javascript.  However, you would need 2 copies of each column:

1. Column to be displayed for an authorised user, not readonly
2. Identical column to be displayed for a non-authorised user, with Element Attributes set to `readonly=readonly`

[Authorisation schemes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b32258/sec.htm#BABEDFGB) can be used to control which columns are displayed to the user.

I was hoping to find a way to do this with a single column and a dynamic value for Element Attributes, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had an error in concept. I wanted to make a tabular form read-only. That's why I couldn't see the "read-only" box. If you open the source for the generated page, each column has given an id with the following naming convention:

```
id="f02_0001"
```

This table cell is in column 2, row 1. So, you can use JavaScript to loop through a column and modify it's properties. In this example, I use jQuery:

```
var payments = $("[id^='f08_']"); // get all cells for column 8

// loop through items
$.each(payments, function(){
   alert($('#'+this.id).val());       
   // make whatever changes you want to this.id, such as make read-only
});
```

Comment: To make this secure, you would need to render the items as readonly initially and have Javascript make them updateable for authorised users.  Otherwise an unauthorised user could potentially circumvent the security by turning off Javascript in their browser.